# Traduction française de "internet friend"? / French translation of "internet friend"?

Tags: traduction

In English we refer to people who we only talk to online, and whom we don't know in real life, as internet friends. I've tried brutishly translating this as *ami d'internet* or *copine d'internet* but the fact that neither of these bring up any google results tells me I'm completely wrong.

What is the term for this in French?

---

En anglais, on appelle les personnes qu'on ne connaît que sur l'internet des "internet friends". J'ai essayé de traduire cette phrase comme *ami d'internet* ou *copin(e) d'internet* mais ni l'un ni l'autre n’apparaît dans les résultats d'une recherche Google (a Google search), donc je crois que j'ai tort.

Quel est le terme français pour "internet friend"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est relativement récent comme phénomène, donc il est difficile de donner une réponse « parfaite », mais je suggère

> ami **sur** internet

car c'est ce que j'entends le plus souvent.

Comment: Pour corroborer ta réponse : [un document](http://www.internetsanscrainte.fr/pdf/theme_2.pdf) utilisé parfois par les enseignants, et simplement une recherche google "un ami sur Internet".

Answer (score 3):

Personnellement, j'utiliserais plutôt

> un ami d'internet

puisque l'on dit un ami d'enfance, ou bien d'école.

Answer (score 2):

Il n'existe pas d'expression standard pour qualifier un "internet friend"
Il faut utiliser une périphrase :

```
"Un ami/Une connaissance d'internet"
"Un ami/Une connaissance connu sur internet"
"Un ami/Une connaissance sur internet"
```

Eviter :

```
"ami virtuel".
```

On dit `"relation virtuelle"` pour qualifier une relation avec un ami d'internet. Mais hors contexte, `"ami virtuel"` est confus et interprété comme `"ami qui n'existe pas vraiment"`

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! Thanks for the answer.